# How to determine which checkboxes are checked in an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, function, checkbox

I have 11 checkboxes in my HTML form and already have a section in my onclick function to determine how many of them were checked, but I would like to be able to tell which of the checkboxes were checked, and possibly just add whichever checkboxes were checked to an arraylist by id/value etc.

EDIT: (Fixed code..?)

```
var formobj = document.forms[0];
    var ingNum = 0;
    checked = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < formobj.elements.length; j++) {
        if (formobj.elements[j].type == "checkbox" && formobj.elements[j].checked) {
                ingNum++;
                 checked.push(formobj.elements[j].value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert the ones checked to an array of their `value` attributes (if `id` attribute, swap `value` with `id`), you could use...

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('your-form').getElementsByTagName('input'),
    checked = [];

for (var i = 0, length = inputs.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputs[i].checked) {
        checked.push(inputs[i].value);
    }
}
```

That will work on any of the older IEs you may care about.

If you have the luxury of only supporting newer browsers, you could use...

```
var checked = [].slice.call(document
               .querySelectorAll('#your-form input[type="checkbox"]'))
               .filter(function(checkbox) {
                         return checkbox.checked;
               })
               .map(function(checkbox) {
                        return checkbox.value;
               });
```

If you were using a library such as jQuery, it's even simpler...

```
var checked = $('#your-form :checkbox:checked')
              .map(function() {
                      return this.value;  
               })
              .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkedBoxes = [];

$("input:checked").each(function() {
    checkedBoxes.push($(this));
});
```

Actually, I think you could just do this:

```
var checkedBoxes = $("input:checked");
```

but I'm not 100% sure if that works.

Comment: Good point, sorry. Still, it could be useful to somebody eventually. :)